# The convergence or divergence of the $1-\frac{1}{2^\alpha}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4^\alpha}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am coming to get some feedback about a problem.

> The convergence or divergence of the $1-\frac{1}{2^\alpha}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4^\alpha}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$ when $\alpha$ has different value.

The following is my solution:

When $\alpha>0$, $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\rightarrow 0$, so according to the Leibniz test, it is convergent.

When $\alpha<0$, it equals $1-2^{|\alpha|}+3-4^{|\alpha|}\cdots$, the even term $2n$ of  the partial sum is $$n\frac{(2n-1)+1}{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{|\alpha|i}=n\frac{(2n-1)+1}{2}-  \frac{2^{|\alpha|}(1-2^{|\alpha|n})}{1-2^{|\alpha|}}\rightarrow -\infty,$$ so the series is divergent.

Can you give me some advice about my solution? Or if there is other solution, looking forward to see it!

Comment: Even easier - for $\alpha<0$, the terms do not even approach $0$.

Comment: The Leibniz test fails here because the terms $1,1/2^{\alpha},1/3,1/4^{\alpha},\dots$ is not monotonically decreasing for any $\alpha\neq 1$

Answer (score 4):

The general term of you series $\sum_{k\ge 1} u_k$ is

$$u_k=\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{(2k)^\alpha}$$

$$=\frac{(2k)^\alpha-2k+1}{(2k-1)(2k)^\alpha}$$

For example, if $\alpha=1,$

$$u_k \sim \frac{1}{4k^2}$$
the series is convergent.

If $\alpha>1,$
$$u_k \sim \frac{1}{2k-1}$$
the series is divergent.

If $ \alpha<1,$
$$u_k \sim \frac{-1}{(2k)^\alpha}$$
the series is divergent.